# Two differ web api project on same port need to deploy

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Can we deploy two web api project in same port because due to some instruction, is it possible? because there is a past work deploy in that port we not have their updated version so we create new project and deploy that on same?

Answer (score 0):

If you host the application on the IIS , you could consider hosting it as nest application.

One application could contains multiple nested application, you could use way to publish two application inside one IIS web sites.

More details, you could refer to below image:

[image]